# Jasmine unit test gives Failed: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined

Tags: angular, jasmine

i am writing a unit test case for a component .
The component looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: ‘test-information’,
  templateUrl: ‘./test-information.component.html',
  styleUrls: [‘./test-information.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TestInformationComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() info: Array<any>;

constructor()
{
}
ngOnInit()
{
}



 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

  console.log(“value”,changes.info.currentValue);

    }

}
```

So basically this component is expected to receive an array of objects as an input.

The test case for this component looks like this

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { TestInformationComponent } from './test-information.component';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../modules/material/material.module';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';


import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';




fdescribe('TestInformationComponent', () => {
  let component: TestInformationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestInformationComponent>;
  let fixture1,hostComponent;
  
  


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    
    
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestInformationComponent],
      imports: [MaterialModule],
      
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestInformationComponent);
    
    
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
        component.info = [
      {
        "id": "19",
        "name": "test”,
        "Score": 36,
    "status": “up”
      
      }
      ];
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
   console.log("componetis ",component);
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  
 
});
```

This simple unit test case is failing,i get the following error:
Failed: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined

I am unable to understand where am i going wrong.

Comment: I copy-pasted this and after correcting names, paths and punctuation it worked. I am guessing you might have omitted the part causing the error. Is there any more code inside `ngOnInit` or `ngOnChanges` ?

Comment: thank you for taking time to execute my code. I examined my code more closely and i observed that in the template , i am using another object "product" which is referenced by the "info.id" . Since i did not define "product" it is causing my test case to fail.